# Emit a signal from another class to main class

Tags: qthread

I got the emit signal working when it is in the **Worker class - def run(self) method**. Everything runs fine, the while loop is able to cycle and emit a signal every 1 second. Then the label will be updated after receiving the signal.

I decided to try out by placing the while loop in another class named loop, methodA. This is to try see if the emitted signal will be picked up by the MainWindow. Unfortunately, the signal is not picked up and the program hung up thereafter.

Did I miss any step that prevented the while loop's emitting signals from being picked up? Kindly point me in the right direction by making changes to my script.

Thanks.

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from mydialog import Ui_mydialog


class Mainwindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_mydialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
        super(Mainwindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.thread = Worker()
        self.loop = loop()
        self.thread.sig.connect(self.updatelabel)

        self.mypushbutton.clicked.connect(self.mypushbuttonclicked)


    def mypushbuttonclicked(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def updatelabel(self, text):
        self.mylabel.setText(text)

class Worker(QThread):

    sig = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent)
        # self.count = 0
        self.loop = loop()

    def run(self):

        self.loop.methodA()

        ## Original code without being in class loop and method loopA
        # while True:
        #     time.sleep(1)
        #     self.count += 1
        #     if (self.count % 1 == 0):
        #         self.sig.emit(f"Timer: {self.count} s")

# Newly added class with method "methodA"
class loop(object):

    sig = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def methodA(self):

        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.count += 1
            if (self.count % 1 == 0):
                self.sig.emit(f"Timer: {self.count} s")



app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Mainwindow()
app.setStyle("Fusion")
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem.
I solved it by following this: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/eventssignals/

The idea is to create a class that hold all the signals, and pass the same communication class to all the classes as a parameter.

So your code might become:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, QObject
from mydialog import Ui_mydialog

class Communicate(QObject):
    sig = pyqtSignal(str) 

class Mainwindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_mydialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
        super(Mainwindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.communicate = Communicate()
        self.communicate.sig[str].connect(self.updatelabel)

        self.thread = Worker(communicate = self.communicate)
        #self.loop = loop() # this seems useless to me here
        
        self.mypushbutton.clicked.connect(self.mypushbuttonclicked)


    def mypushbuttonclicked(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def updatelabel(self, text):
        self.mylabel.setText(text)

class Worker(QThread):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, communicate=Communicate()):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent)
        self.communicate = communicate
        # self.count = 0
        self.loop = loop(communicate= self.communicate)

    def run(self):

        self.loop.methodA()

        ## Original code without being in class loop and method loopA
        # while True:
        #     time.sleep(1)
        #     self.count += 1
        #     if (self.count % 1 == 0):
        #         self.sig.emit(f"Timer: {self.count} s")

# Newly added class with method "methodA"
class loop(object):

    def __init__(self, communicate=Communicate()):
        self.count = 0
        self.communicate = communicate

    def methodA(self):

        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.count += 1
            if (self.count % 1 == 0):
                self.communicate.sig.emit(f"Timer: {self.count} s")



app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Mainwindow()
app.setStyle("Fusion")
window.show()
app.exec()
```

I haven't tested this code, but I hope that you've got the idea.

Comment: i changed this,  self.communicate[str].sig.connect(self.updatelabel) to self.communicate.sig.connect(self.updatelabel)

Comment: Well, I'am really happy to help. the "[str]" tells the signal that it has a parameter as string type.
I made a typo in the programme, it should look like "self.communicate.sig[str].connect(self.updatelabel)".

Comment: Hi Abderrahim, can I assume that whenever I need to emit a signal from another class method, I need to always create a the "Communicate" method. And by doing so I can pass the pyqtsignal into the other external class method.

Comment: I was wondering why can't I place "sig = pyqtSignal(str)" just under class loop(object) ? Why the emit signal don't get picked up?

Comment: @SKDN because by doing so, you're creating a new signal ( pyqtSignal() is the constructor of the pyqtSignal class), hence the hack we've done.
You need to understand that to communicate on the same signal, you must pass the same signal to all the classes that need to communicate between them.
Then, you could just pass the "sig" you have created on the Mainwindow._init()__ to all the classes recursively and that would do the same trick.
I hope you've gotten the idea.

Comment: Another thing, you need to create a Communicate object (by calling Communicate() ) only once and use that object by all the classes that needs to communicate between them. Imagine it like a room that permits all the classes to catch the signal of each one that is on the same room. By creating a new Communicate object in each class, you're separating the classes in different rooms.
You need to understand this to be able to see the things more clearly !

Comment: Thanks, your answers are clear and concise. You have helped me over come something that I was unable to solve for days. I kept trying and trying on my own without being a pest by posting on this forum. Knew i wasn't progressing well and finally seek help. Finally you responded :)

Comment: It's a pleasure to help. The advantage of the **Communicate** Class is that it allows us to group multiple signals in the same object, hence enabling  an effective manner of passing it between multiples classes. I use it for building better signals whenever I use pyQt.
I hope you could go further with this. Good luck. Amicably, Abderrahim.

Comment: Hi Abderrahim, I come across "movetothread", is that similar to my method above just using Qthread? Or "movetothread" is entirely something different? How can I implement "movetothread" on my sample code?